# Accesing files which are currently being written

Tags: file-io

If a file is in a writing process, and at this time if I try to access it like if it is a log file which is being written every 10 milliseconds and I`m trying to access it will I damage or disturb the writing process?

Specifically I'm asking about video files, like if I start a recording process (using Windows Media Encoder) and at this time I would like to monitor the file if it is a blank file (black pixels everywhere) or there is a real content being recorded.

Sorry if my question is a newbie one, but I really really need to be sure about that.

Best on advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can certainly read files as they are being written, without corrupting their content. However:

1. It *is* possible to face an issue if your recording medium cannot deal with the combined data-rate or of both reading and writing. This can be a problem especially with slow-ish USB flash drives.
2. It *is* possible to face an issue on hard drives too, if the combination of reading and writing exceeds the rate of random seeks that the hard drive can handle. This can happen more easily on older drives (e.g. IDE) when dealing with HD video.

The end result is that if you have a real-time writer process, such as a TV recorder, it may be forced to drop some of the data - in the case of video a few frames.

Modern systems have quite fast disk subsystems, reasonably good I/O schedulers and large enough RAM capacities to allow for extensive data caching, which makes it quite unlikely that a single writer/reader combination would saturate the disk subsystem, unless you are doing something unusual like recording several video streams at once.

Keep in mind however, that:

1. The disk subsystem can also be saturated by unrelated processes reading/writing *other* files from the same drive.
2. If you are encoding video, you might also lose frames if something draws enough CPU resources that the encoding process is no longer able to keep-up with the real-time requirements. Depending on the video file, test-playing it might be just enough to do that - at least HD reproduction can be quite demanding. So, watch your CPU load and *experiment* before relying on it to record your favourite show :-)

EDIT:

If you are among the lucky ones that have SSD drives, seeks and data rate should normally be a non-issue. That leaves the CPU - you'd be surprised how easy it is to push it to the limit.

Above all, you should experiment to find out the limits of your system for each particular application. That way you won't have any nasty surprises...

Comment: Thanks a lot ,well i have a Great Machine with Great Performance so CPU Usage is not a Concern because i provide Dual core i7 Processors and about 24 GB of RAM with SS Hard Drives ,but great to know it in details .cheers